# Convenience initializer must delegate with self.init error for custom UIView initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, initialization

I'm trying to create a custom init method for a UIView like so:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, tutorProfileImageURL: String?) {
    self.tutorProfileImageURL = tutorProfileImageURL
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    _ = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TutorArrivedAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
    self.addSubview(customView)
    customView.frame = self.bounds
    tutorImageView.layer.cornerRadius = tutorImageView.frame.size.height/2
    tutorImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

However I am getting the error:

> Convenience initializer must delegate with self.init rather than chaining to a superclass initializer with super.init

Comment: did you follow the suggestion  `super` to `self`?

Answer (score 9):

This error indicates, we shouldn't chain convenience initializer with its super class initializer.

We need to call following method

> super.init(frame: frame)

inside this method

> override init(frame: CGRect)

This is what it looks like:

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, tutorProfileImageURL: String?) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
    self.tutorProfileImageURL = tutorProfileImageURL
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}
```

[Check difference between Convenience and Designation initializers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqZ6zehHKSU)

Answer (score 2):

The convenience initializer uses his init for it. So just change the last line, to self.init

```
convenience init(frame: CGRect, tutorProfileImageURL: String?) {
    self.init(frame: frame)
    self.tutorProfileImageURL = tutorProfileImageURL
}
```